# Extract the first word OR the first and second words from a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with text (Words and numbers) separated by spaces. There are two cases:

Case 1 (3 words separated by 2 space): **BALDOR** 3 hp-4

Case 2(4 words separated by 3 space): **US ELECTRICAL** 75 hp-232

I need to extract the Bolded word(s) (they aren't bolded in the data i have, it's just to illustrate) so I figured I would reverse the order of the words then get rid of the first two (3 hp4 and 75 hp232) which will always output the bolded words.

I might be going about it the wrong way with reversing the order of the words so If you have another method that you think is better do tell.

This is what I have so far:

```
    Sub ExtractMissingInfo2()

    Dim TypeCell As Variant
    Dim Manufacturer As String
    Dim MFG As Variant
    Dim MFGrev As Variant
    Dim MFGout As Variant
    Dim RowCount As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim I As Variant
    Dim wbdata As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet

    Set wbdata = Workbooks("trial1")
    Set wsData = wbdata.Worksheets("Final Data")

wsData.Activate

'Counts how many cells in the chosen column
RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 2 To RowCount 
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(a, 4)) Then
        TypeCell = wsData.Cells(a, 4).Text     'cells with information
        MFG = Split(TypeCell, " ")             'separate them 

    'Reverse the order of the words    
    For I = UBound(MFG) To 0 Step -1
            MFGrev = MFGrev + "" + MFG(I) + " "

           'Use the last iteration which will include all the words in reverse order
                If I = 0 Then
                MFGout = MFGrev
            End If
        Next

    'This part I am not sure about
    Manufacturer = Split(MFGout.Text, " ")(0)

    'Insert extracted words into new column
    Cells(a, 16) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Manufacturer)

    Else
    MsgBox ("Is empty... row " & a)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

So my First issue is that when looping, it keeps adding every string of every cell to the next instead of going through each cell one by one and outputting the words in reverse order.

My second issue is that I am not sure how to delete the first two words after reversing the order.

This is my first question on here so if i made mistakes in the formatting let me know.

Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT:
What I am trying to do is extract the manufacturers' names for a list of equipment. The names can have one or two words in it so that is what i need to extract. I then am pasting those in another column.

The cases I gave where just examples to show the two cases that arise in that list and ask how to deal with them.

Comment: This can be done fairly easy with a formula.

Comment: I cannot get exactly what you want to do? Do you want to extract only 2 words from all of the cells? What do you want to do with them? count them? get the address of cells?

Comment: Are the words bolded in Excel?

Comment: No the words are not bolded in excel. Basically i need the manufacturers' names from that cell. The names can have one or two words in them so that is what i need to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're after this code (explanations in comments)

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractMissingInfo2()
    Dim MFG As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    With Workbooks("trial1").Worksheets("Final Data") 'reference your wanted workbook and worksheet
        For Each cell In .Range("D2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'loop thorugh referenced sheet column D not empty cells from row 2 down to last not empty row

            MFG = Split(cell.Text, " ") ' separate each word

            If UBound(MFG) > 1 Then ReDim Preserve MFG(0 To UBound(MFG) - 2) ' if there were more than two words, keep all but the last two ones

            cell.Offset(, 12).Value = Join(MFG, " ") ' write remaining words into column P same row of current cell
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it works for both cases :

```
Sub test()

Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("US ELECTRICAL 3 hp-2", "BALDOR 3 hp-4")


For j = 0 To UBound(myarray)
    x = ""
    t = Split(myarray(j))

    For i = 0 To UBound(t) - 2
        x = x & " " & t(i)
    Next i

    MsgBox myarray(j) & " ---- " & x
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked as well, just had to change it a little for it to take an array with all the elements in a column.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove the first 3 letters of a string in A1, give this a gander:

```
Dim n As Integer
n = 3
Cells(2, 2).Value = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - n)
```

This assumes the length of the first part of the string is constant which it seems like it is from your example, though you may wish to clarify this. It's not too clear what you're after.

Comment: No i chose poorly for my example, the length of the string i need to remove is variable but will always have two part separated by blanks